# GIT: Reverting last commit?

Tags: git, version-control, dvcs, undo

Which command do i use to revert the changes made by the last commit? The commit was already pushed to the remote server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git undo last commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/git-undo-last-commit)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
git revert HEAD
```

That will back out the most recent commit. Then just push it up.

You can replace `HEAD` with the revision you want out.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you mean by reverting. You want to either do a "real" revert, ie creating another commit which is the exact opposite (diff-wise) of the commit you want to revert, or completely forgetting about the commit.

In the first case, as mentioned: `git revert HEAD`. In the commit message, mention the reason for the revert. Then push the result.

In the second case, `git reset --hard HEAD~1`. However, you'll need to force the push. If you're on branch `master` (and your remote is called `origin`), that would be `git push origin +master`.